# Write.table didn't create file but the script completed

Tags: r

I used a script in R with the purpose of summarize some SNP's on a data frame in R and save them in a tsv file
At the end I used this

```
write.table(overlaps,file"D:/Documents/GWAS/XXXXXXXX.tsv",sep="\t")
```

The console indicated that everything worked fine but the file wasn't there. Nor in my WD that was ./GWAS/
And given the fact that the file was supposed to be about 10 gb I'm kinda worried of where it is because of my remaining storage available

Comment: Are you sure you had a `#` in the name of the data frame?

Comment: No, the # wasn't there it was just to make the comment the question

Comment: Did you write `file"D:/Documents/GWAS/XXXXXXXX.tsv"` or `file="D:/Documents/GWAS/XXXXXXXX.tsv"`?